# How to find the minimum positive number that added to 1.0 gives something larger?

Tags: scheme, racket, numerical

While translating some Fortran to Scheme/Racket I have come across the
function:

```
; EPSILON(X)      The  least  positive  number  that added
;                 to 1 returns a number that is greater than 1
```

How do I find the number in Scheme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#lang racket/base

;; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon
;; approximates the machine epsilon

(require racket/flonum)

(define (compute-machine-epsilon)
  (let loop ([n 1.0])
    (define next-n (fl/ n 2.0))
    (if (fl= 1.0 (fl+ 1.0 next-n))
        n
        (loop next-n))))
```

Comment: Correct, the only thing to look out for is that this assumes we have a base 2 number. There may be cases in other programming languages that it is a BCD.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using IEEE-754 floating-point (which may not be the case in Scheme, I don't know), then the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) is well known: for double-precision arithmetic, it's `1.11e-16`.

For other platforms or floating-point implementations, Wikipedia shows the formula to compute it as (in Haskell):

```
main = print . last . map (subtract 1) . takeWhile (/= 1) . map (+ 1) . iterate (/2) $ 1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a new answer -- it just bothers me that Danny's code makes it look like it's hard to do this kind of thing... it could be simplified to

```
(let loop ([n 1.0])
  (if (= 1 (+ 1 (/ n 2)))
    n
    (loop (/ n 2))))
```

Comment: Maybe I should talk Neil into adding machine-epsilon to racket/math ?

Comment: IIUC, there are a whole bunch of these useful things, right?  He might have some of them in the plot library already.

Comment: Could be. The Science Collection has machine-epsilon already.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are needlessly complicated, and might lead to non-portable code.

The correct answer is, as documented in Racket's [math/flonum package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/flonum.html) is to use the epsilon.0 value, which will be correct for the current machine, and which won't require you to compute it by hand:

```
 (require math/flonum)  
 epsilon.0
```

Comment: Good point. The math/flonum library didn’t exist back in ‘12 though. I guess I succeeded in talking Neil into adding it :-)